# TypeError :state.foo is undefined

Tags: redux, react-redux

When I hit a button that dispatches an action, my app breaks in the reducer. I used to have the filtering in the component but it is cleaner if the logic was in the reducer but the reducer doesn't seem to be able to see the state. It used to be able too.

```js
//reducer.jsx
const initialPizzaOrderStatus =
{
  voteList: [],
  inCount: 0,
  orderLocked: false,
}

const addedVotes = (state = initialPizzaOrderStatus.voteList, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ATTENDANCE_SUBMITTED:
      if (state.indexOf(action.payload.username) !== -1) {
        return state
      }
      return [ ...state, action.payload.username]
    case ATTENDANCE_REVOKED:
      if(state.indexOf(action.payload.username) !== -1)
      {
        return state.filter(function(value){
          return value !== action.payload.username;
        });
      }
      return state
    default:
      return state
  }
}

const countVotes = (state = initialPizzaOrderStatus, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ATTENDANCE_SUBMITTED:
      console.log("countVotes Sub")
      console.log(state)
      if (state.voteList.indexOf(action.payload.username) !== -1) {
        return state.inCount
      }
      return state.inCount+1
    case ATTENDANCE_REVOKED:
        console.log("countVotes Rev")
        console.log(state)
      if(state.voteList.indexOf(action.payload.username) !== -1)
      {
        return state.inCount - 1
      }
      return state.inCount
    default:
      return state.inCount
  }
}

export const pizzaOrderReducer = (state = initialPizzaOrderStatus, action={}) => 
{
  console.log("pizzaOrderReducer Current State: ")
  console.log(state)
  switch(action.type)
  {
    case ORDER_LOCKED:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        orderLocked: true})
    case ATTENDANCE_SUBMITTED || ATTENDANCE_REVOKED:
      return {
        voteList: addedVotes(state.voteList, action),
        inCount: countVotes(state.inCount, action),
      };
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

```js
//action.jsx

import {
    ATTENDANCE_SUBMITTED,
    ATTENDANCE_REVOKED,
} from './constants'

const voteInUnsafe = ( username )  => ({
  type: ATTENDANCE_SUBMITTED,
  payload: {
    username,
  }
});

export const voteIn = (username) => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(voteInUnsafe(username))
}

const voteOutUnsafe = ( username )  => ({
  type: ATTENDANCE_REVOKED,
  payload: {
    username,
  }
});

export const voteOut = (username) => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(voteOutUnsafe(username))
}
```

```js
//VotingContainer.jsx
const VotingContainer = ({ voteIn, voteOut, username }) => (
  <VotingButtons>
    <div className='button-container'>
      <div className='inner-container mt20'>
        <Button 
          variant="contained"
          color="default"
          onClick={() => voteIn(username)}
        >
          I'm In!
        </Button>
      </div>
      <div className='inner-container mt20'>
        <Button
          variant="contained"
          color="default"
          onClick={() => voteOut(username)}
        >
          I'm Out!
        </Button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </VotingButtons>
)

VotingContainer.propTypes = {
  username : PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  voteIn: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  voteOut: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  voteIn,
  voteOut,
}

export default connect(
  null,
  mapDispatchToProps,
)(VotingContainer)
```

I expect it to update the voteList state but it gives me a TypeError when trying to read state in the reducer. See  error below

```
TypeError: state.voteList is undefined
countVotes
E:/Users/Joseph/Documents/GitHub/Pizza Wednesday/ngc.pizza/client/src/reducers.jsx:90

  87 | switch (action.type) {
  88 |   case ATTENDANCE_SUBMITTED:
  89 |     console.log("countVotes Sub")
> 90 |     if (state.voteList.indexOf(action.payload.username) !== -1) {
     | ^  91 |       return state.inCount
  92 |     }
  93 |     return state.inCount+1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing 
`state = initialPizzaOrderStatus.voteList` so `state` won't have a `voteList` in it, is it itself.

change:

```
if (state.voteList.indexOf(action.payload.username) !== -1)
```

to:

```
if (state.indexOf(action.payload.username) !== -1)
```

Edited: 
A better fix could be passing `initialPizzaOrderStatus` object (as initialState) instead `voteList` property only. Then you will get the rest of the properties available in state

```
const addedVotes = (state = initialPizzaOrderStatus.voteList, action) => {
```

->

```
const addedVotes = (state = initialPizzaOrderStatus, action) => {
```

Comment: haha wow I feel so silly now. Don't write code at 3am kids, you end up doing silly stuff!

Thanks Adolfo!

Comment: hehe! best wishes! ;)